# Mecanim + Animation with displacement issues

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, kinematics

I have my game 3D wolf models from animator with displacement i.e wolf transform with animation(not in-place).I have added rigid body on models. I am facing following issues while executing them in my project

1. When i turn on (Checkmark) IsKinematic on my rigid body i.e disable physics animations works perfect with displacement.
   **Issue: I need to have physics enabled on my wolf because it  doesn't detect collision when physics is disabled. and Gravity etc dont have any impact**
2. When turn off IsKinematic(Uncheck) i.e enable physics 
   **animation don't work fine wolf start wobbling and like flying in air.**

Any suggestion and solution will be highly appreciated. Its creating mess since last two days and i am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

What do your colliders look like? It think you have colliders on moving parts of your wolf. If that is the case then your wolf will be supported by your colliders which will cause the wobble when animating.

I would probably try a horizontal capsule collider as it will allow the wolf to slide up and down along any landscape irregularities. This one collider would encapsulate the whole wolf, so the animation will stay inside this collider. Also be sure to freeze at least on axis of rotation to make sure your wolf won't roll. Which one it is depends on how your oriented the capsule but it's probably the Z axis.

You could also have different collider setups but the main things are to make sure the colliders don't animate and the rigidbody should have the correct rotation axes frozen.